# CRM create plugin that executes every 10 minutes

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

Can I create in dynamics CRM plugin that will execute every 10 minutes, after user sign in?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a workflow that executes every 10 minutes.

Comment: How can I call plugin from workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a way to **audit user logon**. This feature was added to Dynamics CRM 2011 in RU 5. See [the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/05/25/auditing-user-logon.aspx).

When enabled, user logon is tracked in the Audit entity. User sign-off is not tracked, because Dynamics CRM sessions are stateless and users are not required to log-off.

It is not possible to audit the Audit entity, so you are not able to hookup a plugin or workflow to the login event. An option could be to query the Audit entity at certain intervals, i.e. by an external process (service or scheduled commandline tool).

**Plugins** can only be triggered by messages issued to the CRM platform. Plugins can not be scheduled; the only way to invoke a plugin repeatedly is by sending messages to the platform by a scheduled process. (Such a message can be as simple as a `RetrieveRequest`.)